# 401 unauthorized error access CSS files MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

First things first, yes I am fully aware this has been addressed here before, however none of the solutions seem to resolve my issue. My problem is simply that I have created a new web project and everything works fine with the default code template that VS2013 has provided, the problem I am currently runing into is adding my own CSS files. This is the process I went through to add them:

`added CSS folder under the already existing Content directory`

`Linked to CSS files in the header CSHTML (I can be sure it is linked properly as it is not a 404 error`

but when i run the project i get: `Status Code:401 Unauthorized` (pulled form the network explorer in chrome dev tools), nothing more. I have tried everything from modifying my config file to setting WindowsAuthentication to true and even moving NTLM to the top, to going into IIS and giving everyone access to every possible function to the CSS directory, been at this for an hour and I'm simply lost, any ideas?

Edit: if it helps at all this is the erro i get when i navigate to one of the CSS files:

[image: error 401 sceen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and I feel incredibly stupid about it, as it turns out all of my css files had encryption set on, i simply had to turn it off: right-click

`*.css file > Properties (General tab) > Advanced button > Encrypt contents to secure data checkbox.`

Works like a dream. If anyone ever purchases a template form ThemeForest, be wary of that.